# Struts 2.5 Java8ClassFinder : 'Unable to read class' error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, struts2, struts2-jquery

I've integrated legacy Struts 2.5 application with Spring Boot 2. Application functionality works but it's throwing this exception on startup, how I can avoid this error? or this is safe to ignore ? thank you

main dependencies I'm using:

- JDK-11.0.4
- String Boot v. 2.2.6
- struts2 v. 2.5.22
- struts2-jquery-plugin v. 4.0.3
- struts2-convention-plugin v. 2.5.22
- struts2-java8-support-plugin v. 2.5.2

my Struts config as below and I'am using annotations based action configrations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.packages" value="com.xxx.yyy.zzz.action"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.classes.reload" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.convention.exclude.parentClassLoader" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    </package>

    <constant name="struts.ckeditor.allowUploads" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.ckeditor.allowedFileExtensions" value="jpg,jpeg,png" />
    <constant name="struts.ckeditor.uploadFolder" value="/imageUploads" />
</struts>
```

Error log on startup

```
07:33.081  INFO 13309 --- [           main] o.a.s.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory   : Initializing Struts-Spring integration...
2020-04-26 11:07:33.081  INFO 13309 --- [           main] c.o.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory    : Setting autowire strategy to name
2020-04-26 11:07:33.082  INFO 13309 --- [           main] o.a.s.spring.StrutsSpringObjectFactory   : ... initialized Struts-Spring integration successfully
2020-04-26 11:07:33.581 ERROR 13309 --- [           main] o.a.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder  : Unable to read class [com.xxx.yyy.zzz.action.IndexAction]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder.readClassDef(Java8ClassFinder.java:442) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder.access$200(Java8ClassFinder.java:61) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.extractSuperInterfaces(Java8ClassFinder.java:495) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.visit(Java8ClassFinder.java:482) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) ~[asm-5.0.2.jar:5.0.2]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder.readClassDef(Java8ClassFinder.java:443) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder.access$200(Java8ClassFinder.java:61) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.extractSuperInterfaces(Java8ClassFinder.java:495) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.Java8ClassFinder$InfoBuildingClassVisitor.visit(Java8ClassFinder.java:482) ~[struts2-java8-support-plugin-2.5.2.jar:2.5.22]
    .......
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.Application.main(Application.java:18) ~[classes/:na]

2020-04-26 11:07:34.078  INFO 13309 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Comment: "**legacy** Struts" + JDK-14.0.1 and you get error. Yeah, not surprising. --- For Java 14 support, you need to upgrade ASM from version 5.0.2 to version 7.2, and hope Struts2 can handle that. See [ASM - Versions](https://asm.ow2.io/versions.html) for detail.

Comment: sorry It was typo.. I meant jdk-11.0.4 (now it's corrected)... anyway after updating it to ASM 8.0 it worked without any issues.. Thank you @Andreas